# Kivy app flashlight not working for Android

Tags: python, android, kivy

I have been trying to create a simple Kivy app that turns a flashlight on and off. I have been trying to fix this for a while to no avail. There isn't much information on the internet for this fix.

I have decided to take a snippet of the code. (The rest is just gui design and it works fine).

```
import json
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window  # For the Background colour
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from datetime import datetime
from plyer import flash

class LockMain(Screen):

    def light(self):  # will turn on the flashlight

        flash.on()
```

So when I install the app on my phone, it opens up to a simple gui screen. When I press a button, the light() function should run. However, it just crashes in my android device.

I did some research and thought it was because I didn't include permissions so I added it.

```
import json
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window  # For the Background colour
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from datetime import datetime
from plyer import flash
from kivy.utils import platform
if platform == "android":
    from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
    request_permissions([Permission.CAMERA,
                         Permission.FLASHLIGHT])

class LockMain(Screen):
    Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)  # Sets the background colour (Canvas) to white


    def light(self):  # will turn on the flashlight

        flash.on()
```

However when I do this, the app doesn't open at all. Is there a fix to this? I'm using android 13.

I looked at the logcat and found these messages

```
2023-02-28 12:46:14.493  1393-8154  ServiceManager          cameraserver                         W  Permission failure: android.permission.CAMERA from uid=10572 pid=30177
2023-02-28 12:46:14.493  1393-8154  CameraService           cameraserver                         E  Permission Denial: can't use the camera pid=30177, uid=10572
2023-02-28 12:46:14.494 30177-30219 CameraBase              org.test.myapp                       W  An error occurred while connecting to camera 0: Status(-8, EX_SERVICE_SPECIFIC): '1: validateClientPermissionsLocked:1545: Caller "org.test.myapp" (PID 10572, UID 30177) cannot open camera "0" without camera permission'
```

Which then causes the app to crash as seen in the logcat below

```
2023-02-28 12:50:39.303 31663-31727 python                  org.test.myapp                       I     File "jnius/jnius_utils.pxi", line 91, in jnius.jnius.check_exception
2023-02-28 12:50:39.303 31663-31727 python                  org.test.myapp                       I   jnius.jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: Fail to connect to camera service java.lang.RuntimeException
2023-02-28 12:50:39.303 31663-31727 python                  org.test.myapp                       I  Python for android ended.
```

Looking at it, it seems like there was some sort of permission error. How do I allow camera permissions for Android using kivy? I tried using android.permissions but it doesn't work.